# Two columns under one groupheader in a Summary Links WebPart 2013

Tags: web-part, xml, project-summary-web-part

Does anyone know how to have two columns (.dfwp-list) under one .groupheader in a summary links webpart?  It seems that with some HTML, a table could be created with two columns, but not sure how to figure it out. Can the XML be edited, and if so, how?  I am not great at XML.

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution!